# My cursor becomes invisible when hovering at curly braces

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting

As title.  So what's the highlight group I need to change? I'm just so tired of finding the needle from the sea(`:hi`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: If you're using Neovim nightly, there is a new command `:Inspect`, which can show **all** highlight-group applied to the currently hovered char by the cursor.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is, this is the [MatchParen](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#hl-MatchParen) highlighting group.

Note: you will find all the default highlighting groups and a short explanation in the help at [:h highlight-groups](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#highlight-groups)

Recent Vims (since [v8.2.4891](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/b3c9077a5be76cd88b9a0c07b6d6c072d5c8ac3e)), even show the group name with their corresponding highlighting inside the help for syntax related items (syntaxt.txt), by making use of [vimhelp.vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/import/dist/vimhelp.vim) a vim9 script that is distributed with vim. This helps to better spot a highlighting group that you may want to adjust to your liking inside your configuration files (or colorscheme).

Comment: Could you also explain this to me: why it's call MatchParen highlight "group"? While I have spent so much time understanding what's a `group` for autocmd, I found it hard to apply the same idea to highlighting... In my perspective, I'm just defining one highlight when calling `:hi MatchParen ...`.

Comment: @job_start it's just a naming convention being used in Vims documentation and source code. I don't know for certain, why it is being called `group` , but I can imagine, this is because it references a *group of highlighting attributes* to be used (e.g. we have forground terminal color, foreground gui color, background terminal/gui color and additional attributes)

Comment: It's very reasonable to me after reading your explanation, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm just so tired of finding the needle

```
:filter /par/ scriptnames
  26: /full/path/to/vim90/plugin/matchparen.vim
Press ENTER or type command to continue

:help matchparen

*pi_paren.txt*  For Vim version 9.0.  Last change: 2013 May 08

          VIM REFERENCE MANUAL    by Bram Moolenaar

Highlighting matching parens            *matchparen*

The functionality mentioned here is a |standard-plugin|.

...

The highlighting used is MatchParen.  You can specify different colors with
                         ^^^
the ":highlight" command.  Example: >

    :hi MatchParen ctermbg=blue guibg=lightblue
...

:scr 26

" Vim plugin for showing matching parens
" Maintainer:  Bram Moolenaar <Bram@vim.org>
" Last Change: 2021 Apr 08
...

  " If a match is found setup match highlighting.
  if m_lnum > 0 && m_lnum >= stoplinetop && m_lnum <= stoplinebottom 
    if exists('*matchaddpos')
      call matchaddpos('MatchParen', [[c_lnum, c_col - before], [m_lnum, m_col]], 10, 3)
                        ^^^
    else
      exe '3match MatchParen /\(\%' . c_lnum . 'l\%' . (c_col - before) .
                   ^^^
        \ 'c\)\|\(\%' . m_lnum . 'l\%' . m_col . 'c\)/'
    endif
    let w:paren_hl_on = 1
  endif
```